# ui router doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, web-development-server

I have a problem after applying ui router page turn into blank.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="storeApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.3.0" data-semver="0.3.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.0/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="services.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

this is the link of the rest of files.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/1tUxa4eV5TjErqc8syM9?p=preview
```

> hint: i use bower and gulp in my project i just modify it to fit plunker.

Image of the index page from project:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally figured out that the problem was in controller.js i include $stateParams in wrong way.**

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues ,

You need to load services.js and controllers.js prior to app.js.

```
   <script src="services.js"></script>
   <script src="controller.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
```

in your plunker you have mentioned `controllers.js` but the file name is `controller.js`

Comment: Thank you for reply , i write it correct on my computer and no thing appeared. and i correct it in plunker and the same problem exist.

Comment: Service and controller load order is after Angular is loaded, not before.

Answer (score 0):

The loading order only matters for jQuery and a few others files. Your load order of AngularUI is fine. This being said, I have found that I typically also need a route for just the root URL.

```
.state('root', {
    url:'',
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl : 'header.html'
        },
        'content': {
            template : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'HomeController'
        },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl : 'footer.html'
        }
    }
})
```

You should also move your JavaScript files to the body and have them appear after the last element on the page. Loading the JS files inline can sometimes have an adverse effect upon the app booting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="storeApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
    <script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.3.0" data-semver="0.3.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.0/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="services.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for replay,i change template : 'home.html', into templateUrl : 'home.html', yes the template appear but the controller and services  don't work

Comment: yes i already did that in my project.i attached the screen shoot of my index page  http://i.stack.imgur.com/AMKSC.jpg